# How can I read a file with varying encoding?

Tags: python, email, character-encoding

Writing code that will read a file in Berkeley mbox format. This is a file containing multiple email messages, each of which may have its own encoding. Code is currently crashing because it encounters a non-utf8 character in the file.

```
    # test; read and print just the headers from an email message
    print("file = %s" % ifile)
    try:
        while True:
            line = ifile.readline()
            print("line = %s %s" % (type(line), line))
            if not line: break
            if line.startswith("From "): break
    except Exception as e:
        print("problem reading file: %s" % e)
        raise
```

generates

```
file = <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/Users/falk/Mail/art2' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>)
problem reading file: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 7081: invalid start byte
```

Does anybody know of a standard way or a utility to handle this, or am I stuck opening the file in binary and figuring out myself? I looked at the email.header and email.message packages and found no joy there.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/mailbox.html#mailbox.mbox…!?

Comment: Hmm. I'm updating old code, and there's a comment that says I rejected mailbox.mbox for some reason I can't remember ("It doesn't do everything I need"), but maybe I should revisit this. I'm actually using the mailbox module elsewhere, when handling entire messages, but this particular code is just for parsing headers; I want to ignore the message body for now. But maybe it's worth parsing the entire message just to get the headers if it's not too slow and it saves me some work.

Comment: OK, adding on .... One thing I wanted was periodic updates as the mbox module reads a mailbox (I'll be working with some absolutely ginormous mailboxes), and the ability to update after more mail arrives in the mbox without needing to re-read the entire thing. Experimenting now.

Comment: For those following along at home; I realized that since I'm only interested in the headers at this point, and email headers are always ascii, I can read the file in binary mode.

Answer (score 0):

Filling in what I've learned to help anybody who was searching for the same question:

If a file, such as a Berkley mbox file, has mixed encodings it is hopeless to attempt to read it as a text file in Python3. You *must* read it in binary mode and figure it out as you go. The `email.message` package does a good job of this, and if you can make it do what you want, then this is what you should use.

In fact, in general, if you don't know what the encoding of a file is, it's not safe to read it in text mode in Python3. Instead, read it in binary mode, and apply `.decode("utf8", errors="replace")` to be safe.

There are very many broken mailers out there. You will get messages with character set encodings Python doesn't recognize. You will find non-ascii characters in headers, even though that's not supposed to happen. You will find emails that don't specify their encoding at all, and you just have to guess.